# Getting values of specific keys from array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects

```
var array = [{"a":11,"b":2},{"a":22,"b":2}]
```

From this, I want a list of values of the key 'a' in all the objects of the array.

```
var res = [11,22]
```

How do I do this as a one liner without writing a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can transform arrays with the `map` function:

```
var allA= array.map(function(o) {
   return o.a;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = [{"a":11,"b":2},{"a":22,"b":2}];

var res  = array.map(function(val){
      return val["a"];
});

console.log(res); // [11, 22]
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you didn't mention `underscore`, but just so you are aware there is a library there that you could do this in one line. The other answers are all better as they don't use any libraries and avail of the native javascript `map` method but I thought it would be good to highlight `underscore`.

```
var array = [{"a":11,"b":2},{"a":22,"b":2}];

_.pluck(arr, "a");
```

You won't get shorter than that. To use this function you need to include the underscore library, and also, you can read the annotated source code here which is a great way to learn javascript to a more advanced level - http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html

Answer (score 0):

// given this array:

```
var arr = [{"a":11,"b":2},{"a":22,"b":2}];
```

// you can do this:

```
var res = arr.map(function (o, i, a) {
    return o.a;
});
```

[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/silkster/r4p2x5L2/)